# How can I set sudo to only give one try?

Tags: linux-mint, sudo

For example, if I type, `sudo synaptic` and enter a wrong password, I get 3 tries to get it right. I want sudo to only give me 1 try and exit with error code 1 if the password is incorrect.

Comment: Answer below, but I think this is a bad idea — it's going to result in passwords typed on the command line in cleartext by accident, because you're not going to change the default everywhere in the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to user terminal (not root) and run `sudo visudo`. 
Default terminal editor should open.
Add these lines:

```
## Allow a user to attempt to enter a password 1 times
Defaults        passwd_tries=1
```

You should be ok.

Also see `man sudoers`

PS: About exit code, in my sudo when i run `sudo ls;echo $?` , after 3 wrong attempts i get exit code 1.